# Do relative URLs not create HTTP requests?

Tags: html, performance, http

Does making an image like

```
<img src="/images/thing.png"/>
```

just go through the physical directory of the local server, or does it do the equivalent of making a request to itself like

```
<img src="http://thesite.com/images/thing.png"/>
```

???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.**

A relative url is a simple way of writing an url (relative to the current url of the current document).

At the end your browser has an **url**, and has to run an HTTP request (if the protocol of this url is http) to retrieve the targeted document.

Note that the server is doing nothing, all the job is made by your browser (which rebuild the absolute url from the realtive url format -- with a starting / or not-- and the current document url). 
So talking about 'browsing itself' makes no sense, the server can present a lot of different urls, some targeting other servers, some targeting the same server. At the end the browser reads the url and sends a request (and a relative url will quite certainly reach the same server but that's not even sure, several physical servers could be used to manage the same domain, some other actors between your browser and the final server may decide that for that url another system has to be contacted).